# Is gravitational potential always defined for a system?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, potential, potential-energy

I have studied about **Gravitational potential energy ($GPE$)** and **Gravitational potential ($GP$)**. ..while everywhere it is said that $GPE$ is always of a system as it depends on the *configuration* of the particles with respect to each other ...but nothing as such is said about it in my books..so my question is...

1)is $GP$ also defined for a system like say two particles...??

A)I think it is true because ..$GP$ and $GPE$ are very much related..

B)But then I also think it is not true because of the definition I have that Gravitational potential at a point is also defined as..***The work done per unit mass by an external agent in bringing a particle slowly from the reference point to the given point.***

2)But nothing is being said about another particle(system) in this definition..

3)I am also really confused..with these terms $GP$ and $GPE$ because there are different definition of these in different places..{I took The standard definition of $GPE$ from (***Resnick,Halliday***) but the book doesn't talk about $GP$}...

Can someone please clarify these??it will be of great help.

Comment: $GPE$ is gravitational potential energy. $GP$ is gravitational potential energy *per mass*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What is gravitational potential?**

Usually a *potential* is defined as the *potential energy* ***per mass*** or ***per charge*** or similar. This is most often seen in relation to electricity or chemistry and less often to gravity.

$GPE$ is gravitational potential energy. $GP$ is gravitational potential energy *per mass*:

$$GP =\frac{GPE}{m} $$

**Is it defined for the system or the object?**

*$GPE$ is the amount of energy that can potentially be used as work for pulling an object towards the source*. It depends on both the source's mass $m$, on the mass of the other ("target") object $m_0$ as well as on the distance $r$ between them ($G$ being a universal constant):

$$GPE=-G\frac{m m_0}{r}$$

*$GP$ is the amount of energy that can potentially be used as work for pulling **one kilogram of mass** towards the source*. It gives an easier basis for comparison as it does not depend on the specific target object's properties anymore:

$$GP=\frac{GPE}{m_0}=-G\frac{m}{r}$$

BUT it still depends on the distance $r$ between them. $GPE$ is system dependent as it depends on both the object properties and on the system configuration, but even though $GP$ does not depend on the object properties, and thus is defined for the source object alone, it still depends on the system configuration. If no other object was present in the near neighbourhood (if $r\rightarrow \infty$), then $GP\approx 0$.

Comment: .so does that means GP is also of a system(say ..two particles)..(by this equation)

Comment: Hi @Freelancer, I have now found the time to elaborate and answer the full question. See the edited answer. Hope this solves it.

Comment: OK..so you said..and I quote ***"$GP$ is the amount of energy that can potentially be used as work for pulling one kilogram of mass towards the source"*** or..$$GP=\frac{GPE}{m}$$..

Comment: so why  cant I also say ***$GP$ is nothing but $GPE$ of two particles where the mass of one of the particles is 1kg*** after all this is also doing the trick for us just like the deffinition you gave..and then to make the fancy equation we can write $$GP=\frac{-G×m×1Kg}{r}$$..which is same like the one you gave(*notice..I have emphasized the 1kg mass here*)..so can we also use this definition I gave ..is it OK..is this equation and your equation same..??

Comment: Yes, it's OK. If you have a 1 kg mass. You might consider an object as made up of many 1 kg masses. The $GP$ is the potential energy associated with each of these small masses. The $GPE$ is then just the total (the sum) for the whole object.

Comment: So my definition (above) is also right??

Comment: Well, yes. It is right for a 1 kg mass.

Comment: Unfortunately it is wrong...and that is why things like these are confusing me very much..its very complicated...and there are different definitions in different places...which are very delicate..

Comment: As by dimensional analysis..my equation 
$$GP=\frac{-G×m×1kg}{r}$$ ..gives on RHS the dimensions  of $$\frac{[L]^2[M]}{[T]^2}$$..
but the dimensions of the equation you gave..
$$GP=\frac{GPE}{m}$$ ..on the RHS gives..$$\frac{[L]^2}{[T]^2}$$..which clearly shows that your equation(correct one).. is very different from my equation(wrong one)..even though the difference isn't clearly visible...because dividing by mass($m$)[which you did] and putting it equal to 1...are very different things...though not much different..

Comment: That is why..even though this explanation you gave ***"GP is the amount of energy that can potentially be used as work for pulling one kilogram of mass towards the source"*** isn't actually very clear to me...it is not that intuitive ..so can you expand just this part a little bit...

Comment: ***Note:sorry for making this very long..(which ultimately led to you saying my definition is also right!!)...but I wanted you to understand what is creating confusion for me***

Comment: I have been trying to understand it for a while..but most of the books..haven't explained $GP$ (like resnick halliday)..I even asked a separate question on this..but still haven't got any really good explanation which clears all my doubts..http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/217521/defining-gravitational-potential/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31454/discussion-between-steeven-and-freelancer).

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31454/discussion-between-steeven-and-freelancer

Answer (score 0):

> is GP also defined for a system like say two particles

Yes.

You can admire in the attached picture the [Contours of Equal Gravitational Potential](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mechanics/lagpt.html) for the system Earth - Moon.

*[image: Contours of Equal Gravitational Potential]
[Contours of Equal Gravitational Potential](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mechanics/lagpt.html)*

Comment: The figure you're shown here is not exactly the gravitational potential. It is the effective potential in the rotating frame (that is it has a centrifugal pseudoforce contribution computed in).

Comment: There is no need of any centrifugal force. Because the moon moves around earth, in any point of the orbital plane there will be a time changing potential $V(x, y, t)$ or $V(\omega, r, t)$. Such a time varying potential is quite ugly and not quite suggestive but once you have its mathematical expression you can find, by pure math (the laws of mechanics being no longer involved), a convenient rotating reference system where variable time, $t$ disappears and you get what is called the Contours of Equal Gravitational Potential.

Comment: I'm not suggesting adding one, it is already in the figure you are showing.

Comment: The map "Contours of Equal Gravitational Potential" was not computed using the "centrifugal pseudo-force" concept. It is also not $V(x, y, t_0)$, it is not a picture of $V(x,y)$ at moment $t_0$. The map is exactly what I have already explained in my previous post.